# How to get ten of recently added items using AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to get ten of recently added items (sorted by creationDate) using AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression. Here's my code:

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];

    AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = @"userId = :authorName AND creationDate > :creationDateVal";
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":authorName": @"me", @":creationDateVal": @0};
    queryExpression.limit = @10;
    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[Post class]
                     expression:queryExpression]
     continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
         if (task.error) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
         }
         if (task.exception) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
         }
         if (task.result) {
             AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
             NSLog(@"paginatedOutput = %@", paginatedOutput.items);

         }
         return nil;
     }];
```

I'm getting limited ten items, but these items are the first that I have added to the table, not last.

Comment: Are you trying to get the last 10 items of creationDate?

Comment: @notionquest yes. Thank you

Comment: Below answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the last 10 items by sort key (i.e. creationDate in the above scenario) , you can use **ScanIndexForward = false (Descending Order)**.

> ScanIndexForward — (Boolean) Specifies the order for index traversal:
>   If true (default), the traversal is performed in ascending order; if
>   false, the traversal is performed in descending order.
>
> Items with the same partition key value are stored in sorted order by
>   sort key. If the sort key data type is Number, the results are stored
>   in numeric order. For type String, the results are stored in order of
>   ASCII character code values. For type Binary, DynamoDB treats each
>   byte of the binary data as unsigned.
>
> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order
>   in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default
>   behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in
>   reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the
>   client.

**Note on Limit:-**

You need to query until LastEvaluatedKey is null.

> Limit — (Integer) The maximum number of items to evaluate (not
>   necessarily the number of matching items). If DynamoDB processes the
>   number of items up to the limit while processing the results, it stops
>   the operation and returns the matching values up to that point, and a
>   key in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation, so that
>   you can pick up where you left off. Also, if the processed data set
>   size exceeds 1 MB before DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the
>   operation and returns the matching values up to the limit, and a key
>   in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the
>   operation. For more information, see Query and Scan in the Amazon
>   DynamoDB Developer Guide.

Comment: the code for **scanIndexForward**: `queryExpression.scanIndexForward = @NO;`. Thank you